# imagejpeg no funciona en Xampp Windows 10

Tags: php, base-de-datos, apache, archivo, xampp

> Quiero almacenar una imagen en mi servidor con localhost, pero parace
> que imagejpeg() no esta guardando la imagen, busque en otros lugares y
> resulta que son los permisos de escritura e php, como cambio dichos
> permisos, Estoy en windows.

---

Editado:

Bueno, triby comento que los permisos no podrian ser debido a que estoy ejecutando xampp en win10, pero aun asi no alamacena la imagen y nisiquiera lanza mensaje de error, alguien tiene idea?

Comment: ¿Tienes Windows 10 o alguna versión de servidor? Si es el primero, dudo que sea problema de permisos, porque por defecto están habilitados, a menos que la carpeta tenga específicamente el atributo de solo lectura.

Comment: ¿No funciona la ruta con constantes mágicas? p.e. `$path = __DIR__ . '/archivos/';`

Comment: Aun no lo pruebo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que al guardar la imagen, php no toma como directorio principal a htdocs sino que a el disco local, es decir unidad "C", lo unico que hice fue excribir imagejpeg($lienzo,"C:/xampp/htdocs/archivos/".$namefinal.$ext);

donde "$lienzo" es la imagen creada segudo de la ruta y extension del archivo.

Espero ayudar a alguien.